# Finding the root path from the given path

Tags: c#, path

If string `path = "\\ProgFiles\\sampleDir\\annet.dll"`
I want to take `"\\ProgFiles\\sampleDir"` alone from the path in a seperate string variable using c#. Do I have any inbuilt option for this? I am using visual studio 2008 and .net compact framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);`

Be aware that there are some nuances with this method (like returning null for a root directory): check out the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.90%29).

Comment: And do I have any option of retrieving sampleDir alone from path??

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class.
It contains a Method "GetDirectoryName". That's what you should need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class to do that, just try something like this

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("Your path here");
string dirName = fi.DirectoryName;
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try:

```
String path = "C:\\ProgFiles\\SampleDir\\annet.dll";

String newPath = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("\\"));
```

The syntax may be a little out (i have not tested it), but definitely look up .Substring and .LastIndexOf methods on strings!

Comment: No stringparsing. The other answers point to System.IO.Path which is what you should use.

Comment: Indeed. One reason would be that the `Path` methods work correctly with forward slashes, too.